# adding increase arrow in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I want to add a increase arrow on top of the first column of the highchart to the last column?
How to I dynamically set the height of the arrow according to the height of first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Renderer.path](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) which allows to add custom shape.

```
r.path(['M', startX, startY, 'L', startX, startY - 20, endX - 20, startY - 20, endX - 20, startY - 40, endX, startY - 10, endX - 20, startY + 15,endX - 20, startY, 'Z'])
    .attr({
        zIndex:9999,
        fill:'red',
        stroke: 'green',
        'stroke-width': 2
    })
    .add()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qx4snpvb/

Comment: Hey can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419932/adding-labels-exactly-above-x-axis-categories-in-highcharts also I am not able to figure out x,y of the text relative to the graph