# adding labels exactly above x-axis categories in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, renderer

I tried to put labels but I am not able to locate the exact location of xAxis_categories realtive to graph.
So if width is varied text gets disturbed and not remained aligned with categories
http://jsfiddle.net/akataria/qx4snpvb/8/

```
startX = chart.xAxis[0].minPixelPadding + chart.xAxis[0].left ,
startY = chart.plotTop,
debugger;
r.text('19% yoy increase ', startX , startY)
.css({
color: '#4572A7',
fontSize: '11px',
}).add();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render the text once, then look at the bounding box of the Element to determine the width of the text, and then use this information to create a correctly positioned text by rendering it again.

For example:

```
var element = r.text('19% yoy increase ', 0 , 0)
.css({
    fontSize: '11px'
}).add();

var width = element.getBBox().width;
element.destroy();

r.text('19% yoy increase ', data[0].plotX + chart.plotLeft - (width/2) , startY)
.css({
    color: '#4572A7',
    fontSize: '11px'           
}).add();
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qx4snpvb/12/) for a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks ondkloss :) I also figured it out here http://jsfiddle.net/akataria/qx4snpvb/9/